# Animated.timing() with negative delay

Tags: animation, react-native, react-animated

I have created one animation in react-native using `Animated.timing()` where I want to start animation mid-way. Is there any way to apply negative value to delay like [this](https://css-tricks.com/starting-css-animations-mid-way/) in css. My sample code is like below:

```
Animated.timing(this.state.animatedVal, {
  toValue: 100,
  duration: 500,
  easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
  delay: 200,
}).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, negative delay isn't a thing... However, you could use `setValue` on your animated value before starting animation to get the same effect. IT would really depend on your use-case for the animated value, since it may cause an abrupt jump in animation, but since you want to start it midway anyway, this should work for example:

```
this.state.animatedVal.setValue(50);
Animated.timing(this.state.animatedVal, {
  toValue: 100,
  duration: 250, // the portion of the time of the full animation
  easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
}).start()
```